# How do I temporarily enable package installation without any permission prompt

Tags: package-management

Whenever I need to install an app using the package installer, there will be a prompt asking for admin user's name and password. How do I temporarily turn this feature off, so that any package can be installed automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to go into your System Preferences, and into Security & Privacy

[image]

Then unlock - if needed - the lock on bottom left, and select "Anywhere".
The computer might ask you for your password.

[image]

When you're done, you should be able to open and install many .DMG installers without being prompted for a password.

When you are done, you can revert these settings as they are a good security to prevent third party apps from installing automatically on your computer.

Comment: Strangely, everything in the general tab is greyed out even after i unlock it. Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: Could you try repairing your permissions in Disk Utility, and restarting (while leaving the lock open), and trying again, see if you still run into this greyed out problem?